# VS Code yarn install error: Command: node-gyp rebuild, Directory: /vscod/node_modules/native-watchdog

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-gyp

Using yarn install to build VS Code throws "node-gyp rebuild" errors.

- Version of VS Code: 1.50.0
- Operating System: macOS 10.15.7
- Node.JS, x64, version v12.19.0
- yarn version 1.22.10
- Xcode version Version 12.0.1
- Python version 2.7.16

Following Error:

```
aquilas-iMac:vscod1 amora$ yarn
yarn install v1.22.10
$ node build/npm/preinstall.js
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info vscode-windows-ca-certs@0.2.0: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "vscode-windows-ca-certs@0.2.0" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info vscode-windows-registry@1.0.3: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "vscode-windows-registry@1.0.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info windows-foreground-love@0.2.0: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "windows-foreground-love@0.2.0" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info windows-mutex@0.3.0: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "windows-mutex@0.3.0" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info windows-process-tree@0.2.4: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "windows-process-tree@0.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > gulp-tsb@4.0.5" has incorrect peer dependency "typescript@^3.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/15] ⢀ keytar
[2/15] ⢀ native-is-elevated
[3/15] ⢀ native-keymap
[4/15] ⢀ native-watchdog
error /Users/amora/Documents/GitHub/vscod1/node_modules/native-watchdog: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/amora/Documents/GitHub/vscod1/node_modules/native-watchdog
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info using node@12.19.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python"
gyp info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/amora/Documents/GitHub/vscod1/node_modules/native-watchdog/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/amora/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.2.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/amora/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.2.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/amora/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.2.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/amora/Documents/GitHub/vscod1/node_modules/native-watchdog',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/watchdog/src/watchdog.o
In file included from ../src/watchdog.cc:9:
/Users/amora/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.2.1/include/node/uv.h:24:2: error: unterminated conditional directive
#ifndef UV_H
 ^
In file included from ../src/watchdog.cc:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:72:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/unistd.h:132:1: error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier
struct accessx_descriptor {
^
In file included from ../src/watchdog.cc:9:
/Users/amora/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.2.1/include/node/uv.h:473:1: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
UV_EXTERN uv_buf_t
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/amora/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.2.1/include/node/uv.h:47:20: note: expanded from macro 'UV_EXTERN'
# define UV_EXTERN __attribute__((visibility("default")))
                   ^
../src/watchdog.cc:82:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'uv_thread_create'
    uv_thread_create(&w_monitor_thread_id, w_monitor, NULL);
    ^
../src/watchdog.cc:121:41: error: expected '}'
NAPI_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init);
                                        ^
/Users/amora/Library/Caches/node-gyp/9.2.1/include/node/uv.h:27:12: note: to match this '{'
extern "C" {
           ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/watchdog/src/watchdog.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/amora/Documents/GitHub/vscod1/node_modules/native-watchdog
```

I was working on this issue for hours. Node-gyp is really a Pain !

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

> In case of issues, try deleting the contents of ~/.node-gyp (alternatively ~/.cache/node-gyp for Linux or ~/Library/Caches/node-gyp/ for macOS) first and then run yarn cache clean and then try again.

But another error comes：

```
...
...
...
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/amora/Documents/GitHub/vscode1/extensions/markdown-language-features/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/amora/Documents/GitHub/vscode1/extensions/markdown-language-features/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.19.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/Users/amora/Documents/GitHub/vscode1/extensions/markdown-language-features/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/electron-v9.2-darwin-x64/fse.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-electron-v9.2-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-electron-v9.2-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-electron-v9.2-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and electron@9.2.1 (electron-v9.2 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-electron-v9.2-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-electron-v9.2-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and electron@9.2.1 (electron-v9.2 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http Connection closed while downloading tarball file
...
...
...
```

Tried many many times, including checking the network.

Cannot download `fse-v1.1.3-electron-v9.2-darwin-x64.tar.gz`